# What is the scope of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

(IF anyone who understands the phenomena have better idea for the title, please edit)

I thought I understood this, it turns out I am missing something. I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: refreshAtEndOfProgress is not defined`. if the function and its reference are in different `<script>` blocks:

The following code is within one single web page:

```
<script>
    // Note: I am passing the function itself (not calling it) is intentional, it's a callback
    // Got 'Uncaught ReferenceError: refreshAtEndOfProgress is not defined' in the following line:
    var someVariable = new SomeMyObject(refreshAtEndOfProgress);
</script>

<script>
    function refreshAtEndOfProgress() {
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
    }
</script>
```

However in case the function and its reference are within the very same script block, then all is OK, no error message:

```
<script>
    // No error this case:
    var someVariable = new SomeMyObject(refreshAtEndOfProgress);

    function refreshAtEndOfProgress() {
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
    }
</script>
```

I though it does not matter if the code is within the same or different `<script>` blocks... Obviously I am missing something.

Comment: You thought wrong. It doesn't execute the second script tag until after it has executed the first script tag.

Comment: All the script tags are in the same global scope. But nothing defined in the second tag is known about when executing the first one.

Comment: My bad. Sorry for the duplicate, I could my prev search better by using the following search term: scope multiple script tag